# Spring boot authentication loadbalancer URL

Tags: java, spring, authentication, nginx

My environment looks like this at the moment (example addresses):

```
database <-> spring boot app (localhost:8080) <-> web-serwer(nginx) (localhost:8081)
```

The application uses authentication (jdbc) and here come my issues.

1. When currect user is not authenticated and tries to open secured URL (let's say `localhost:8081/admin`) it is redirected to login site however URL then becomes `localhost:8080/login` (embeded tomcat server) and from that moment every request is made directly to tomcat.
2. When current user is not authenticated and tries to open login page directly(`localhost:8081/login`), after successful login he again gets redirected to tomcat url (`localhost:8080`).
3. When "surfing" through pages without authentication or after (manually changing URL) everything works as expected (base URL stays same).

I guess it's about spring boot authentication config. Any ideas how to "fix" it, so that base URL is always the one of the loadbalancer? Will using AJP (atm it simple redirection) solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set your redirect page to "/login", instead of specifying the hostname in there? (Which I'm assuming you're doing, but you didn't provide code about how you're configuring the `HttpSecurity` instance from Spring Security.

If that doesn't work - and it's likely it won't - you may need to configure Spring Security to disable automatic metadata generation in its XML configuration file.

There's actually a Github issue for Spring Security on just this problem, and how to fix it, step by step: [Github Issue with this question, and its response](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/168)

TL:DR: Remove(?) `<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>` from your securityContext.xml file:

I believe if you do this it will reset the URLs to just use `/`, instead of the whole hostname, and that should work.